# Bug in sklearn.cross_validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Potentially bug exists in `sklearn.cross_validation` using `LeaveOneOut`.
The `x_test` and `y_test` are not used in `LeaveOneOut`. Instead, the validation is done using `x_train` and `y_train`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut, cross_val_predict

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])             
y = np.array([12,13,19,18,15])
clf = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
cv = LeaveOneOut(len(y))
for train, test in cv:
    x_train, y_train = x[train], y[train]
    x_test, y_test = x[test], y[test]
    y_pred_USING_x_test = clf.predict(x_test)
    y_pred_USING_x_train = clf.predict(x_train)
    print 'y_pred_USING_x_test: ', y_pred_USING_x_test, 'y_pred_USING_x_train: ', y_pred_USING_x_train



y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 13.2] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 14.3  15.4  16.5  17.6]
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 14.3] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 13.2  15.4  16.5  17.6]
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 15.4] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 13.2  14.3  16.5  17.6]
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 16.5] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 13.2  14.3  15.4  17.6]
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 17.6] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 13.2  14.3  15.4  16.5]
```

The `y_pred_USING_x_test` is giving one value at each for loop, which has no meaning!

The `y_pred_USING_x_train` is what looking for by using `LeaveOneOut`.

The result from the following code is completely irrelevant!

```
bug = cross_val_predict(clf, x, y, cv=cv)
print 'bug: ', bug
bug:  [ 15.          14.85714286  14.5         15.85714286  21.5       ]
```

Any defense is welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by "which has no meaning!".

Comment: Why are you training the model on full data set and predicting values from the same dataset. Validation should be done using unknown (previously not seen) values, if not model will seem to perform better during validation, but will perform poorly in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `clf = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)' after the for loop, it gives the same answer ascross_val_predict(clf, x, y, cv=cv)` its no more bug. The program is predicting with the one left sample for each loop.

Answer (score 2):

According to [LeaveOneOut](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut.html#sklearn.cross_validation.LeaveOneOut)

> Each sample is used once as a test set (singleton)

That means `x_test` will be an array of one element, and `clf.predict(x_test)` will return an array of one (predicted) element. This is seen in your output.

`x_train` will be the training set with without the one element chosen for `x_test`. This can be confirmed by adding the following lines in the for loop

```
for train, test in cv:
    x_train, y_train = x[train], y[train]
    x_test, y_test = x[test], y[test]
    if len(x_test)!=1 or ( len(x_train)+1!=len(x) ): # Confirmation
        raise Exception
    y_pred_USING_x_test = clf.predict(x_test)
    y_pred_USING_x_train = clf.predict(x_train)
    print 'predicting for',x_test,'and expecting',y_test, 'and got', y_pred_USING_x_test
    print 'predicting for',x_train,'and expecting',y_train, 'and got', y_pred_USING_x_train
    print
    print
```

**Note** This is not a proper validation as you are training and testing your model on the same data. You should create new `LinearRegression` object in iteration of for loop and train it using `x_train`, `y_train`. Use this to predict `x_test` then compare `y_test` and `y_pred_USING_x_test`

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])             
y = np.array([12,13,19,18,15])
cv = LeaveOneOut(len(y))
for train, test in cv:
    x_train, y_train = x[train], y[train]
    x_test, y_test = x[test], y[test]
    if len(x_test)!=1 or ( len(x_train)+1!=len(x) ):
        raise Exception
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred_USING_x_test = clf.predict(x_test)
    print 'predicting for',x_test,'and expecting',y_test, 'and got', y_pred_USING_x_test
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no bug. Two things:

1. You are performing the cross-validation split, but you never train on the training set! You need to call `clf.fit(x_train, y_train)` before calling `predict()` for it to behave as you expect.
2. By design, the test set in `LeaveOneOut` is a single sample (i.e. the *one* being left out), so the predicted result will also be a single number. The `cross_val_predict()` function is a convenience routine that stitches together these single outputs.

Once you account for these two things, I believe the output of your code will make more sense.

Here are the results:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import LeaveOneOut, cross_val_predict

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])             
y = np.array([12,13,19,18,15])
clf = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
cv = LeaveOneOut(len(y))
for train, test in cv:
    x_train, y_train = x[train], y[train]
    x_test, y_test = x[test], y[test]
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train) # <--------------- note added line!
    y_pred_USING_x_test = clf.predict(x_test)
    y_pred_USING_x_train = clf.predict(x_train)
    print('y_pred_USING_x_test: ', y_pred_USING_x_test,
          'y_pred_USING_x_train: ', y_pred_USING_x_train)

print()
print(cross_val_predict(clf, x, y, cv=cv))
```

Output:

```
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 15.] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 15.5  16.   16.5  17. ]
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 14.85714286] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 13.94285714  15.77142857  16.68571429  17.6       ]
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 14.5] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 12.3  13.4  15.6  16.7]
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 15.85714286] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 13.2         14.08571429  14.97142857  16.74285714]
y_pred_USING_x_test:  [ 21.5] y_pred_USING_x_train:  [ 11.9  14.3  16.7  19.1]

[ 15.          14.85714286  14.5         15.85714286  21.5       ]
```

As you can see, the test outputs in your manual loop match the output of `cross_val_predict()`.